# Dynamic var origination from JSON object

Tags: python, json

this is going to be a kinky one... well it is for me as I've been trying to nail it for a week with no success so far :(

Lets say I get a nested JSON response from an API hit as:

```
{"Parameters":    {
  "Name":       {
     "Unparsed": null,
     "First": "John",
     "Middle": "A",
     "Last": "Smith",
     "Suffix": "Jr"
  },
  "Address":       {
     "Unparsed": null,
     "Line1": "123 Main St",
     "Line2": "apt.2",
     "City": "New York",
     "State": "NY",
     "Zip": "12345"
  }
```

and I wanted to create a variables dynamically from the key and assign value from the key's value.

I know how to do it like with name_first = data.get("Name").get(First), but in this case I am highly dependable on JSON response structure and above wont work if the structure is changed (renamed keys, added or deleted key) etc.

So I am working on writing a python script to do it, but so far had no luck getting this nailed.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use `locals().update` to update current variables. So, this snippet creates new variables, like *Address_Line2*, *Name_Suffix*, etc

```
from collection import deque
import json
st = deque()
st.append(([], json.loads(your_json)['Parameters']))
while len(st):
    prefix, item = st.pop()
    if isinstance(item, dict):
        for k, v in item.items():
            st.append((prefix + [k], v))
    else:
        print({'_'.join(prefix): item})
        locals().update({'_'.join(prefix): item})
```